# Twitter/twemproxy on Windows

Tags: windows, caching, redis, twemproxy

**Is any chance to run twemproxy on windows server?** Is there a Windows port of twemproxy? Or similar program for Windows?

Why twemproxy on Windows?

1. Because we have web applications that running under IIS.
2. I want to  reduce network communication between
   webserver-twemproxy-redis. I    would like to instal twemproxy right
   on the webserver and communicate    over network only between
   twemproxy and redis servers.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter/twemproxy doesn't support Windows.

I have viewed the source code, the only platform-dependent code is the network-related (event notification, socket connect/read/write) part, it won't be too hard to port it into a Windows application.